# Inserting auto generated id in sqllite using java

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, auto-generate

I am writing java application using sqllite

```
public Product createProduct(String productName) throws SQLException {
    String query = "INSERT into tbl_Product (name) values (?) ";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Product product = null;
    try {
        connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        //preStatement.setInt(1, 0);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, productName);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } finally {

        //preparedStatement.close();
        DbUtil.close(rs);
        DbUtil.close(preparedStatement);
        DbUtil.close(connection);
    }
    return product;

}
```

My product table have (ID,Name) column, where Id is auto generated. What all java changes are required so that preStatement can insert auto generated id in db.

Comment: setString(1,productName) because you have only 1 parameter

Comment: This is error I am geting                                                                                                e = (java.sql.SQLException) java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table tbl_Product has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied) in this case.

Comment: You need to explicitly specify the columns you want to insert, eg `INSERT into tbl_Product(name) values (?)`

Comment: I think it worked and go to next statement but when I do preStatement.executeQuery(); or preStatement.executeUpdate();  I got following exception,                                                                   Exception occurred in target VM: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver 
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver

Answer (score 0):

String query = "INSERT into tbl_Product  values (?) ";

```
ResultSet rs = null;
Product product = null;
try {
    connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    preStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
    preStatement.setString(1, productName);
    rs = preStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Nope, I have Column(Id,Name). If I give preStatement.setString(1, productName);, it complain about inserting in only one column. How my auto generated Id should be inserted in preStatement?

Comment: before execute add prep.addBatch();
prep.executeBatch();

Comment: HIString sqlQuery = "INSERT into tbl_Product  values (?) ";                
               PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);  
               stmt.setString( 1, "val" ); //nameText variable contains the text of the jtextfield) 
                stmt.executeUpdate();               Its work fine......:)

Answer (score 0):

```
String sqlQuery = "INSERT into tbl_Product  values (?)                 
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);  
stmt.setString( 1, "val" ); //nameText variable contains the text of the jtextfield) 
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

use execute update instead of execute query.

`executeQuery()`:

> Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

`executeUpdate()`:

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

Comment: I still get same error     e = (java.sql.SQLException) java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table tbl_Product has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied) . R you using sqllite?

Comment: please check you put Autoincrement to id

Comment: Please check you create table like this.CREATE TABLE tbl_Product (id integer primary key auto increment, name varchar(20)); else delete table create use this query then try it.

Comment: This is my table    CREATE TABLE `tbl_Product` (
 `Id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 `Name` TEXT NOT NULL
     );

Comment: Please execute its manually and update me.
INSERT INTO tbl_Product (Name)VALUES ( 'java' );

Comment: It works fine if done manually. But when I run java code I got error.

Comment: Hi You mentioned  Exception occurred in target VM. This exception occured 
 
i thing your query return single record and you are trying fetch more than that.

Comment: I have copied my complete method. I am not calling any loop or iterator to fetch more than one record.

Comment: Hi please add  connection.commit();

Comment: try {
        connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        //preStatement.setInt(1, 0);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, productName);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();
    } finally {

Comment: Hi Did you solve that problem?

Comment: Yes.. Thanks man.. solution was INSERT into tbl_Product(name) values (?) as suggested by  @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: hi Mark Rottevee edit my submission. Please accept the answer.